# Solving this Second Order D.E

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this second order D.E.

```
eq[t_] = x''[t] - (D[Log[solx[t]], t] + D[Log[Abs[D[x[t], t]]^2], t]) (x'[t]^2 + Abs[x'[t]]^2)
```

where:

```
solx[t_] := -0.7 (0.0015 + t)^(-2)
```

But both the analytic or numeric solutions give errors:

```
DSolve[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t] // FullSimplify
```

Or

```
NDSolveValue[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[1] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

The initial conditions are so arbitrary. So any help to make these solutions work ?

Answer (score 5):

The OP adds that `x[t]` is to be complex. Since `D[]` treats functions as complex analytic and `Abs[]` is not differentiable anywhere, one is forced to deal with the real-analytic components `Re[x[t]]` and `Im[x[t]]` of `x[t]`.  It was easier to just "see" how to write the problematic term in terms of these parts than to figure out how to get *Mathematica* to transform the original equation.

```
D[Log[ComplexExpand[Abs[D[u[t] + I*v[t], t]]^2]], t]
(term = 2 Re[x'[t] Conjugate[x''[t]]]/Abs[x'[t]]^2) /. 
   x -> Function[t, u[t] + I*v[t]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*
>   (2 u'[t] u''[t] + 2 v'[t] v''[t])/(u'[t]^2 + v'[t]^2)
>   (2 u'[t] u''[t] + 2 v'[t] v''[t])/(u'[t]^2 + v'[t]^2)
> *)
> ```

```
ClearAll[x, t, solx, eq];
solx[t_] := -7/10 (15/10000 + t)^(-2)

eq[t_] = x''[t] - (D[Log[solx[t]], t] + term) *
    (x'[t]^2 + Abs[x'[t]]^2);

DSolve[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

> ```
> (*  $Aborted  (killed DSolve[] after a minute or so) *)
> ```

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 8/10, x'[0] == -1/40 + I/40}, 
  x, {t, 0, 10}]

ReImPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> [image]

If you really want to solve a BVP as in the OP — it seems an off-handedly tossed-out problem, though — use your understanding of the problem to pick good `"StartingInitialConditions"`.

---

*Original answer, assuming `x[t]` is real as it is in the example*

1. Use exact coefficients, not floating-point (inexact) numbers.
2. `Abs` is the complex absolute value and is not differentiable. Use `RealAbs` or apply `ComplexExpand` to it or its derivative.

This gives a solution:

```
ClearAll[x, t, solx, eq];
solx[t_] := -7/10 (15/10000 + t)^(-2)

eq[t_] = x''[
   t] - (D[Log[solx[t]], t] + 
     D[Log[RealAbs[D[x[t], t]]^2], t]) (x'[t]^2 + RealAbs[x'[t]]^2)

DSolve[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]
```

BVP's are difficult to solve if the ODE is prone to singularities.  This gives a solution:

```
NDSolveValue[{eq[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[1] == -1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: The `RealAbs` changes seems to matter more than conversion to exact coefficients.

Comment: @Michael E2. Thanks. But x[t] is a complex function. I don't want to use `RealAbs` cause that makes it real.

Comment: @Dr.phy The `DSolve` and `NDSolve` problems you proposed were real-only, so I assumed `x[t]` was real.

Comment: @Dr.phy I meant to point out, besides why I assumed `x` was real, that I added a complex solution, too.